# Auth page in standard blazor template infinite looping in InteractiveServer render mode

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-8.0

If i create a new Blazor Web App in Visual Studio, and modify *App.razor* to to globaly use InteractiveServer render mode, the auth page starts recharging in an infinite loop.

This is the edited line:

```
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

What is the reason of this behaviour?
There is any way to use global interactivity mode with identity framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem, it's a navigation loop in the AccountLayout.razor page because it wants to use HttpContext but can't in Interactive mode so attempts to refresh the page to get a static version. Because interactive is set globally its never static and so gets itself stuck in an endless loop.

I gave my answer in the following question after finding it was a known issue  (that should be resolved for future) and found a posted workaround: [Blazor, .Net 8 and Global Interactivity issue with Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599233/blazor-net-8-and-global-interactivity-issue-with-identity/77599354#77599354).