# Blazor, .Net 8 and Global Interactivity issue with Identity

Tags: blazor, identity, mudblazor, .net-8.0

I have been playing around with the new .Net 8 Blazor templates and ran into a problem with Identity and setting a global InteractiveServer render mode. The change I made was in the App.Razor file to the :

```
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

The reason I added this was because I was also attempting to get MudBlazor integrated and this was required for it to run properly (as far as I could tell at least). MS does list the ability to do this via docs as well so appears to be a legitimate choice to make to set this global render mode.

The issue I then faced was with any page using the AccountLayout component e.g. Login, Register, ResetPassword etc because it loops on this part:

```
if (HttpContext is null)
{
    // If this code runs, we're currently rendering in interactive mode, so there is no HttpContext.
    // The identity pages need to set cookies, so they require an HttpContext. To achieve this we
    // must transition back from interactive mode to a server-rendered page.
    NavigationManager.Refresh(forceReload: true);
}
```

As it's globally set it's always hit so goes into an endless navigation loop. I attempted to set the account layout and/or account pages to use a rendermode of null, default, static etc but they don't seem to be valid options nor can I find any examples of anyone doing this.

So my question is, does anyone know of a way to either set default/static on a component for render mode OR know of a way to get MudBlazor working in .net 8 project without using global interactive mode? I have obviously tried setting the rendermode to interactive on relevant pages using mudblazor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that this is currently an issue that appears to be getting fixed by MS. Within the issues I did find a workaround for now within this raised issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51476

Essentially changing the rendermode globally in app.razor based on the url:

```
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account") ? null : InteractiveServer;
}
```

Can confirm I have tried this and have Identity pages and MudBlazor working on other pages as originally intended. At least it appears future templates should already contain the resolution for this.